# Jquery Image Swap onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change the src of a set of images of a class to each image's title attribute. Is there any easier way to do this?

```
    <img src="" title="images/1.png" class="images" />
    <img src="" title="images/2.png" class="images" />
    <img src="" title="images/3.png" class="images" />
    <img src="" title="images/4.png" class="images" />
    <img src="" title="images/5.png" class="images" />
<script>
    $(function(){
    var newImage = $(this).attr('title')
    $('.images').attr(src, ''+ newImage +'');
    });
</script>
```

But this does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't, because you're getting the title from just the first image.  Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('img.images').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('src', $this.attr('title'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SwcYK/

```
$(function()
{
    var $images = $("img.images");

    for (var i = 0; i < $images.length; i++)
    {
        $images[i].src = $images[i].title;
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, a lot of people (including me) need to learn from you how to write readable code.

Comment: I tried writing this for statement before but i was using the [i] in the variable $images lol. This helped a lot thanks!

Comment: @Eric I just try to write in such a way that it is easy for me to remember what I was trying to do at first glance. Sometimes if we end up writing to fancy and tricky code it makes it difficult to come back and remember what you were doing at first glance. 
@Adam Glad to help!